# “docker-compose up” Error : Cannot start service fetcher: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:344

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm running docker on a ubuntu server. For a while everything was working well, then the docker stoped and when I tried to put it up again i had this error :

```
ERROR: Service 'back' failed to build: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"/bin/sh\": stat /bin/sh: no such file or directory": unknown
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2"
services:
  back:
    build: ./crypto_feed_back
    restart: always
    command: node server.js
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
  front:
    build: ./crypto_feed_front
    restart: always
    command: npm start
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app/
    depends_on:
      - back
  fetcher:
    build: ./crypto_feed_fetch
    restart: always
    command: /usr/sbin/crond -l 2 -f
    depends_on:
      - postgres
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: crypto_feed
      POSTGRES_DB: crypto_feed
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
  caddy:
    image: elswork/arm-caddy:1.0.0
    restart: always
    environment:
      ACME_AGREE: "true"
    volumes:
      - ./caddy/Caddyfile:/etc/Caddyfile
      - ./caddy/certs:/root/.caddy
    ports:
      - 80:80/tcp
      - 443:443/tcp
    depends_on:
      - front
```

And back's Dockerfile :

```
FROM node:alpine

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install --production

# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production
COPY ./api/ ./api/
COPY ./server.js .

EXPOSE 3001

CMD npm start
```

If someone has an idea on how I can solve this, it would be really nice !

Comment: if everthing worked and the stop docker made this then there is 2 options:  restart docker service, or run `aa-remove-unknown` it removes stuck connections ( im not sure) and it caused by appArmor in ubuntu

Comment: It was that simple, just restart the service, thank you !